# Adding the "Play Again?" feature on my random number guessing game in Java

Tags: java

I have been stuck on this and can't seem to loop again when user is asked to continue. Would a do-while loop be more appropriate for this type of play again feature? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class HiLo

{
   public static void main( String[] args )  
{
  boolean again = true;

  while (again == true)
  {
  int MAX = 100;
  int MIN = 1;
  int guessCounter = 1;
  int outOfRangeCounter = 0;
  int userGuess = 0;
  Random rand = new Random();
  int computerGuess = rand.nextInt(MAX) + MIN;
  System.out.printf("Welcome to the game of Hi-Lo...\n\n\n");
  System.out.printf("I have chosen a random number for you to guess.\n\n");
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  String repeatAgain;


  while (userGuess != computerGuess)
  {   
     System.out.printf("Guess %d: Enter a number between %d and %d: ",guessCounter,MIN,MAX);
     userGuess = keyboard.nextInt();
     if (userGuess == computerGuess)
     {
        System.out.printf("%d is correct\n\n",userGuess);
     }
     else if (userGuess > MAX || userGuess < MIN)
     {
        System.out.printf("%d is not between %d and %d\n\n",userGuess,MIN,MAX);
        outOfRangeCounter++;
     }
     else if (userGuess > computerGuess)
     {
        System.out.printf("%d is too high\n\n",userGuess);
        MAX = userGuess - 1;
        guessCounter++;
     } 
     else if (userGuess < computerGuess)
     {
        System.out.printf("%d is too low\n\n",userGuess);
        MIN = userGuess + 1;
        guessCounter++;   
     }       
  }
  System.out.printf("It took you %d valid guesses to find the number.\n",guessCounter);
  System.out.printf("You had %d out of range guesses.\n\n",outOfRangeCounter);
  System.out.printf("Do you want to play again? (Y or N): ");
  repeatAgain = keyboard.nextLine();
     if (repeatAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
           again = true;
        }
     else
        {
           again = false;
        }
   }         
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `repeatAgain = keyboard.nextLine();` with `repeatAgain = keyboard.next();` and it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

nextLine() skip a line and returns the line that was skipped.

```
        //change
        //repeatAgain = keyboard.nextLine();
        //to
        repeatAgain = keyboard.next();
```